# Why some div fit in the whole width some are not?

Tags: css, html

Here is the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/thisisblake/DUALJ/

My questions is: Why column2 fits the whole width of the parent `div` while column1 doesn't?

Comment: because you instructed for it not to.

Comment: if you tell something to be 480px wide, why would you expect it to be 100%? `width:480px;` + `padding: 10px` = 500px. #wrap = `width:750px;`

Comment: OK, I got it, because I set the color of `column2` and `wrap` the same one, so I thought the column2 fit the whole width..

Answer (score 2):

It is due to this line on the css:

```
#main {
  width: 480px; // This one
}
```

If you remove that width, it will fit the entire column.

Answer (score 2):

It has to do with the `width: 480px;` If you were to change that line to `width: 100%;` it will fill the entire width of the container.

Before:

```
#main {
    /*  float:right;*/
    width:480px;
    padding:10px;
    background:#9c9;
}
```

After:

```
#main {
    /*  float:right;*/
    width:100%;
    padding:10px;
    background:#9c9;
}
```

Comment: hey, I have also set the width to column2, but it still fit the whole width

Answer (score 1):

you specified a width of 480 px for main, so that is the width that it will be constricted to.
Here is your code with that line removed: http://jsfiddle.net/DUALJ/1/

```
#main {
/*  float:right;*/
    padding:10px;
    background:#9c9;
}
```